# JavaScript reference inside HTML not loading in modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a main page, and I am loading modal dialogs that are stored as HTML in other partial html pages. I am loading modals dynamically into 1 modal in the page on different buttons clicks.

The partial page for my modals look like this for 1 page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../App/modals.js"></script>

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Specify entity name you wish to create</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <form>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" id="txtEntityNameCreate" />
            </div>
            <p class="modal-log"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEntity()">Create Entity</button>
</div>
```

I am referencing a script at the top which will be responsible for resetting the text field inside dialogs. I might use it for later purposes as well. But the script is not loaded into the page when I am calling the dialog like this from my main page:

```
<a  id="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mainModal" 
   href="modals/createmodal.html"
   data-remote="modals/createmodal.html" 
   onclick="Utilities.SetFocusModal('txtEntityNameCreate')">
    <img src="../Images/create.png" />
    <h4>Create Entity</h4>
</a>
```

How can I load the modals.js when the dialog is loaded?

Thanks.

Comment: you specify `href` twice in the link

Comment: thanks, just modified it

Comment: maybe try putting the script tag in the main page instead

Comment: what if the user didn't click any link to show dialog, why loading it in the main page?

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe the things in your `<a>` tag are dependent on modal.js being loaded

Comment: No, things in my <a> tag don't have anything to do with modal.js, modal.js will be used only after the page is loaded.

Comment: Ok yeah I don't know. It seems like a problem with where you are putting the script tag, but hard to tell from your info what's going wrong. Does the console give you anything when you click the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When bootstraps modals are loaded remotely they do not reload the dom so the page is not being reloaded into the modal the html is just being inserted, so your script is more than likely not executing, not really sure what your script looks like but that is more than likely the issue.  Bootstrap has a jquery function for when the modal is shown.  So if your script functions correctly when you load your html normally, like when you open just your snippets, then you can probably do something like the following on your main page:

```
$('#mainModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  //then put your script here
});
```

or maybe

```
$('#mainModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $.getScript('path/to/script.js');
});
```

And then your script will execute when the #mainModal is shown.